# Generate gradient progress bar

Tags: android

[image: Gradient Image]

I am using below code for displaying gradient in progress bar. So how to create a gradient progress bar as displayed in the above image? I have tried many solutions but haven't succeeded yet.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="@color/gray"
                android:centerColor="@color/gray"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="@color/gray"
                android:angle="270"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dip" />
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                    android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                    android:angle="270"
                    />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners
                    android:radius="5dip" />
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="@color/dark_yellow"
                    android:endColor="@color/dark_yellow"
                    android:angle="270" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: http://tutorialsface.blogspot.in/2014/09/gradient-circular-progress-bar-tri-color.html

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In your case `@android:id/secondaryProgress` is not necessary. Additionally, `android:angle=270` will rotate gradient from top to the bottom, so it's perpendicular direction to desired.

All you need is:

#### drawable/gradient_progress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
            <solid android:color="#fff"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
            <gradient
                android:endColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                android:startColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

#### layout/any_layout_file.xml

```
<ProgressBar
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/gradient_progress"
    tools:progress="60"
    />
```

Comment: This is almost working, just need to wrap the item with id/progress with <clip></clip> tag

Comment: Need to add <clip></clip> like below or else progress value will not be considered. 
```<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <corners android:radius="5dp" />
                <gradient
                    android:endColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
                    android:startColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>```